# Infinite Series $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(t)\sin(t)dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $f$ is a function such that:

- $f$ is continuous
- $f$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(t)=0$

Then what can we say about the series $\stackrel{+\infty}{\sum}u_n$
with:$$u_n = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(t)\sin(t)dt$$

**Edit:**

- Since $f$ is continuous, decreasing and converges to $0$. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+ \colon \enspace f(x)\geq0$
- Since $|\sin x| \leq 1$ we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty}f(x)\sin (x) = 0$

Comment: Pretty much nothing, I guess, by considering the instances $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ and $f(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I added more conditions on $f$.

Comment: With the added conditions, you can show the series converges using the alternating series test and upper and lower bounds on $f$ in each interval

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ meets the hypothesis and additionally is differentiable we have

$$ \int_{0}^{M}f(t)\sin(t)\,dt \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}f(M)(1-\cos M)-\int_{0}^{M}f'(t)(1-\cos t)\,dt $$
where the first term in the RHS goes to zero as $M\to +\infty$ and the second one converges to a constant.
 Indeed $-f'(t)$ is non-negative due to the monotonicity of $f$ and

$$ f(0)-f(M)=\int_{0}^{M}-f'(t)\leq\int_{0}^{M}-f'(t)(1-\cos t)\,dt\leq 2\int_{0}^{M}-f'(t)\,dt=2(f(0)-f(M)) $$
so the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)\sin(t)\,dt$ is convergent in the improper Riemann sense and the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}u_n$ is at least conditionally convergent. If $f$ meets the hypothesis but is not differentiable you may apply the same argument to the convolution between $f$ and a smooth kernel and reach the same conclusion by invoking density arguments.
 As a simpler alternative you may notice that $\sum_{n\geq 0}u_n$ is convergent by Leibniz' rule:
$$ a_n = (-1)^n u_n = \int_{0}^{\pi} f(t+n\pi)\sin(t)\,dt $$
and since $f$ is decreasing to zero
$$ a_n-a_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left[f(t+n\pi)-f(t+(n+1)\pi)\right]\sin(t)\,dt $$
is non-negative and convergent to zero.